# Can you exploit emscripten-compiled Wasm to run arbitrary JavaScript?

Tags: security, emscripten, webassembly

I'm trying to understand the threat level of the following scenario in a web application:

- Web app contains a C++ component compiled to Wasm by Emscripten
- Runs 3rd party Wasm blobs (assume fully untrusted)
- Assume neither blob can call back to JS via import/export
- All Wasm blobs share memory

So, obviously a malicious blob could clobber the memory used by the C++ component. I'm wondering how likely it is that it could somehow run arbitrary JS in the context of the web app, ie. inject a script via some of the hooks emscripten puts into Module.

Thanks!!

Comment: "All wasm blobs share memory" Do you mean the situation that all WebAssembly modules shares the same WebAssembly.memory instance?

Comment: Yes! So assume a malicious blob can bypass other security mechanisms and corrupt the memory used by the emscripten-ed C++ code. I'm ok with the app breaking at that point: I'm wondering if the attacker could get arbitrary JS execution through the JS interface generated by emscripten.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to inject arbitary JS code if imported functions have `eval` or something, but AFAIK WASM only knows function signatures and it is designed to block access outside of its memory and WASM currently does not have dynamic import, which make your case much harder to happen. I'm not an expert in security but I don't think SO is the right place to ask such qeustions because it worth a CVE if there is an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the insights. I'd be happy to mark this as an answer.